# Connect to Remote server from any internet connection via ssh

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh

While at work i connect to the local desktop from my laptop via ssh by connecting to same internet connection.But How to do the same with any internet connection.I know this question has been asked before, but the answers i have seen are either links or explanations.

Can anyone please suggest specific commands i could run to connect to the server with any internet connection.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with local? Is the computer you are connecting to in the same network and you are trying to access it from outside this network?
(I can't comment yet.)

Comment: Ah , Yes. I want  to access it from an outside network, by outside network i mean  any internet connection/from anywhere.

Comment: Okay so the problem here is that your computer you are trying to connect to is not reachable from outside the network (not even visible). Only your network as a whole is visible from outside. So you need a way to access your network from outside and then connect to your computer via SSH. 
The keyword you are looking for here is [VPN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhYeqgufYss).

Comment: The basic idea is that you create a VPN connection (or "tunnel") to the network your target computer is in. So you basically enter your network from outside and pretend if you were actually in the network. That way you target computer gets reachable over its standard local IP.

Comment: okay let me check